# Updating urql cache without a mutation

Tags: graphql, jwt, urql

I'm working on a fullstack project that has a GraphQL backend and uses JWT for authentication. My access and refresh tokens are stored in the localStorage in the frontend.

When a user logs out, I just clear the tokens from localStorage and I further want to reset the cached query that fetches the logged user, so it returns null (meaning there is not a logged in user anymore). But, I am not excecuting a mutation. Everything is happening client-side. I can't put the mutation name in urql's cacheExchange `updates` object and update the cache when the mutation is excecuted.

I thought I could just add a mutation on the backend that's called `logout` and just returns true, but I really believe there is a more elegant way to do that.